# MDX Solution: Extract 1 Record Per Group and Add to Main Resultset

Tags: sql, ssas, mdx, resultset, dimension

I have a very simple fact/dimension schema for use with real estate data within a SSAS 2008 R2 database.

I would like to construct a result set outlining when a house was first sold, its selling price, as well as what the house's value is after being sold in monthly increments.

Please consider the following dimensions and measures:

## Dimensions:

---

### DimHouseNumber

HouseNumber

---

### DimValuationDate

ValuationDate

---

### DimSoldDate

SoldDate

## Measures:

SoldAmount
CurrentValue 
CountofHouse

1. The [DimHouseNumber].[HouseNumber] attribute hierarchy represents the house number
2. The [DimSoldDate].[SoldDate] attribute hierarchy represents the date the house was sold.
3. The [DimValuationDate].ValuationDate attribute hierarchy represents the date the house was valuated after being sold.
4. The [SoldAmount] measure represents what the house original sold for.
5. The [CurrentValue] measure represents the current value of the house AFTER being sold based on the [DimValuationDate].ValuationDate attribute hierarchy member in question.

This being said, consider the following result set containing all possible tuples and measures based on the dimensions and measures outlined above:

---

### HouseNumber | Sold Date | Sold Amount | Valuation Date | Current Value

```
 1                  1/3/2011        $100,000.00     1/31/2011           $100,000.00
 1                  1/3/2011        $100,000.00     2/28/2011           $110,000.00
 1                  1/3/2011        $100,000.00     3/31/2011           $112,000.00
 2                  1/20/2011       $50,000.00      1/31/2011           $51,000.00
 2                  1/20/2011       $50,000.00      2/28/2011           $53,000.00
 2                  1/20/2011       $50,000.00      3/31/2011           $75,000.00
```

One can see above that the sold date and sold amount values remain the same for each month the house number in question is valuated based on how the underlying fact table is configured.

The records that are inserted into the corresponding fact table represent MONTHLY valuations of the houses once they are sold.

This being said, I would like to turn the result set above into what is shown below:

---

### HouseNumber | Valuation Date | Current Value

```
 1                    1/3/2011        $100,000.00 
 1                    1/31/2011       $100,000.00 
 1                    2/28/2011       $110,000.00 
 1                    3/31/2011       $112,000.00 
 2                    1/20/2011       $50,000.00 
 2                    1/31/2011       $51,000.00 
 2                    2/28/2011       $53,000.00 
 2                    3/31/2011       $75,000.00
```

You can see above I am trying to create a chronological timeline of what the house was valued at INCLUDING when it was sold.

Essentially, for each house that is sold, I would like 1 record outlining the value of the house and the valuation date.

You can see that what differentiates the 2 result sets above is that the 2nd one above includes the date the house was sold and what it sold for as part of a "valuation" period.  The 1st result set above only includes dates AFTER the house was sold.

I am in need of generating the 2nd result set above based on the data contained within the 1st result set outlined above.

Unfortunately, I do not have the luxury of modifying the source data on the OLTP side or on the SSAS cube itself, and am in need of an MDX only solution for this.

I would appreciate if someone could please show me the required MDX statement needed to accomplish this based on the dimensions and measures I outlined above.

You help is greatly appreciated!

Comment: Perhaps your could post the complete spec for your application. There's not much to go on here.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you've all the days available in [DimValuationDate], you might try the following calculated measure:

```
with 
    member [Measures].[Value] as 
           iif( not isEmpty( ( [Measures].[Current Value], [DimValuationDate].currentMember )),
                ( [Measures].[Current Value], [DimValuationDate].currentMember ),
                iif( not isEmpty( ([Measures].[Sold Amount], LinkMember( [DimValuationDate].currentMember, [DimSoldDate] ))),
                     ([Measures].[Sold Amount], LinkMember( [DimValuationDate].currentMember, [DimSoldDate] )),
                     null
                )
            )

select 
    [Measures].[Value] on 0,
    non empty [DimHouseNumber].members * [DimValuationDate].members on 1

from 
    [my-cube]
```

Comment: Thank you Marc for the quick response.  I tried your solution.  As outlined above, my requirements would be for the [valuationDate] dimension on the axis to reflect both the SoldDate OR the ValuationDate.    IN essence, if we reference the first result set I posted above, we would be adding 1 additional record per HounseNumber reflecting the SoldAmount and SoldDate,   Your solution only references the [DimValuationDate] dimension on the axis and not the [SoldDate].  Any ideas?  Thanks for your help!

Comment: Would it be possible to somehow extract the first record tied to each HouseNumber, reference the SoldDate and SoldAmount, and then add it back to the main result set?  I'm thinking maybe 1 set could pull the first record per HouseNumber, and this could somehow be cross joined back to the main result set effectively adding the additional records as originally intended?

Comment: Do not understand; is your [DimValuationDate] having all the days? 'coz in the calc. member [Value] I propose, I'm performing a LinkMember() into the [DimSoldDate] ... So the [DimValuationDate].members on the axis will be either Valuation or Sold date. If the assumption is wrong, do you have a Time dimension will all the days then ?

Answer (score 0):

This seems to be a simple UNION query:

```
select *
from ((select distinct HouseNumber, SoldDate as ValuationDate, CurrentValue
       from fact
      ) union all
      (select HouseNumber, ValuationDate, CurrentValue
       from fact
      )
     ) f
order by HouseNumber, ValuationDate
```

This query combines the sales data with the valuations data.

Comment: Thank you Gordon for the response.  I am unable to modify the underlying Fact data within the underlying data source via T-SQL, and so I am restricted to using MDX against the existing cube structure as is with no modifications permissible to the SSAS OLAP cube I am referencing.  It would be great if I could somehow figure out how to transform your T-SQL you posted above to an MDX equivalent query.

Comment: I think MDX supports union (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms146030.aspx).  However, I did see the "SQL" tag first and responded with SQL.